# Unity Networking: Unity crashes when I call the NetworkManager.singleton.StopClient() function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, stack-overflow, unity3d-unet

So basically, all i want to do is to disconnect a user when he presses a button.
I've added the NetworkManager.singleton.StopClient(); function on my customNetworkManager script, which inherits from the NetworkManager class.
But whenever I press the button to disconnect the player, unity stops responding.
Someone said on another post that maybe unit gets stuck in a while loop while executing the function

So here is my Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.Networking.Match;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class customNetworkManager : NetworkManager {
UIManager UImanager;
void Start()
{
    UImanager = gameObject.GetComponent<UIManager> ();
}
public void SelectedWan(){
    NetworkManager.singleton.StartMatchMaker();
    UImanager.showWAN ();
}
public void StartHost()
{
    Setport ();
    NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost ();
    UImanager.showGameOn ();
    UImanager.showIPAddress ();
}
public void JoinGame()
{
    string ip = GameObject.Find ("ipfield").transform.Find ("Text").GetComponent<Text> ().text;
    if (ip == "")
        return;
    setip (ip);
    Setport ();
    NetworkManager.singleton.StartClient ();
    UImanager.showGameOn ();
}
//call this method to request a match to be created on the server
public void CreateInternetMatch()
{
    string matchName= GameObject.Find ("roomName").transform.Find ("Text").GetComponent<Text> ().text;
    if (matchName == "")
        return;
    NetworkManager.singleton.matchMaker.CreateMatch(matchName, 2, true, "", "", "", 0, 0, OnInternetMatchCreate);
}

public void FindInternetMatch()
{
    string matchName= GameObject.Find ("roomName").transform.Find ("Text").GetComponent<Text> ().text;
    if (matchName == "")
        return;
    NetworkManager.singleton.matchMaker.ListMatches(0, 10, matchName, true, 0, 0, OnInternetMatchList);
}

private void OnInternetMatchCreate(bool success, string extendedInfo, MatchInfo matchInfo)
{
    if (success)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Create match succeeded");

        MatchInfo hostInfo = matchInfo;
        NetworkServer.Listen(hostInfo, 9000);

        NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost(hostInfo);
        UImanager.showGameOn ();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Create match failed");
    }
}
public void disconnect(){
    Network.Disconnect ();
    if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("localPlayer").GetComponent<WizardScriptNet> ().isServer) {
        print ("host");
        NetworkManager.singleton.StopHost();
    } else {
        print ("client");
        NetworkManager.singleton.StopClient();
    }

}

//call this method to find a match through the matchmaker

//this method is called when a list of matches is returned
private void OnInternetMatchList(bool success, string extendedInfo, List<MatchInfoSnapshot> matches)
{
    if (success)
    {
        if (matches.Count != 0)
        {
            //Debug.Log("A list of matches was returned");

            //join the last server (just in case there are two...)
            NetworkManager.singleton.matchMaker.JoinMatch(matches[matches.Count - 1].networkId, "", "", "", 0, 0, OnJoinInternetMatch);

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No matches in requested room!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Couldn't connect to match maker");
    }
}

//this method is called when your request to join a match is returned
private void OnJoinInternetMatch(bool success, string extendedInfo, MatchInfo matchInfo)
{
    if (success)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Able to join a match");

        MatchInfo hostInfo = matchInfo;
        NetworkManager.singleton.StartClient(hostInfo);
        UImanager.showGameOn ();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Join match failed");
    }
}

void Setport ()
{
    NetworkManager.singleton.networkPort = 7777;
}

void setip(string Address)
{
    NetworkManager.singleton.networkAddress = Address;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and was disappointed there were no answers. I found out that since I was trying to call StopClient() while hosting, I needed to call StopHost() instead.

I created this little block to call the appropriate function depending on if I am the Host, Server, or Client:

```
NetworkIdentity networkIdentity = GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>();
NetworkManager networkManager = NetworkManager.singleton;

if (networkIdentity.isServer && networkIdentity.isClient) {
    networkManager.StopHost ();
} else if (networkIdentity.isServer) {
    networkManager.StopServer();
} else {
    networkManager.StopClient();
}
```